# jed in s-lang: always wrap long lines in all buffers

Tags: buffer, word-wrap, s-lang

(NOTE: I don't have a high enough score here to create a `jed` tag on this question, even though it would be ideal to have that tag here.)

I'm using the `s-lang`-based `jed` editor, and I want it to automatically wrap lines at the wrap column whenever jed is displaying a buffer.

In `/etc/jed.rc`, I have this ...

```
HORIZONTAL_PAN = -1;
WRAP = 79;
```

However, wrapping only occurs when I am entering text. I want all the buffers with lines longer than 79 characters to wrap the lines on the screen without physically breaking up the long lines.

In other words, if I have a long line in a file which looks like this ...

```
col 1                                    col 79
|                                        |
v                                        v
beginning [... stuff ...] data things whatever more stuff
```

I want it to look like this on the screen in `jed`, assuming that column 79 occurs at the "t" in the word "whatever" ...

```
col 1                                    col 79
|                                        |
v                                        v
beginning [... stuff ...] data things what
ever more stuff
```

But when I save the file, I still want the line to be saved in the file as one long line, as follows:

```
col 1                                    col 79
|                                        |
v                                        v
beginning [... stuff ...] data things whatever more stuff
```

Is this even possible in `jed`? If so, does anyone know how to configure `jed` to behave in this manner? Perhaps via some special `s-lang` code ... ???